# How to read the script back after script load into redis instance.?

Tags: lua, redis

Let's say I had loaded a script into redis, can I read the script later again troubleshooting? 
For example, can I read back "return 100" from

```
script load "return 100"
evalsha 22cd37f569ce84333afb93ba232d04d5aa6bb87a 1 key val
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot not read again the script.
It has to be created and stored by your application. Redis just put it in a cache.
If you want to debug your script, you can use the [script debug command](http://redis.io/commands/script-debug).